# iPad App Store link not showing iPhone apps

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

I am trying to make a button to link to my other apps on the App Store on an iPad. My other apps are all for iPhone; this app I am working on is the only app I have developed for iPad. Opening the app store on an iPad normally and doing a search allows the option to select iPad only apps or iPhone only apps, but when I use a link to go from my app to the app store, I get no results because it looks like it is only displaying iPad apps and I only have iPhone apps to display.

Is there a way to make the app store show iPhone apps from a link, or is not being able to view iPhone apps from a link just an App Store "feature"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iphone Apps are not shown on iPads, by design.
You can show all your apps by replacing the App link with your name or company name, but still only iPad apps though.
You could also make your Apps Universal if it´s appropriate for your Apps.

Comment: What? All iPhone apps can run on an iPad.